# View Resource Based Policies in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I created this permission (I believe its called resource based policy) using my terraform script. How can I view the create policy using AWS console?

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch" {
  statement_id   = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action         = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the lambda console, select your function. Then in the configuration section click the key icon. The lambda function policy will appear below the designer.
[image: Lambda console screen shot]